# Export Excel Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, export

I have a problem when exporting excel, the file can be downloaded but when opened it is empty. this is the code on the Frontend side:

```
onExportToExcelClicked() {
    const payload = {
        SNoba: this.noBa,
    };    this.http.post(`${environment.inventarisasiUrl}/api/inv/t/invent/detailsexcel`, payload, {
        responseType: 'blob' // Set response type to blob
    }).subscribe(
        (blob: Blob) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            const a = document.createElement('a');
            //a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = `${this.noBa}.xlsx`;

            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();

            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
```

Data appears when downloading excel

Answer (score 0):

maybe it takes time to write in a file. it depends on size of your data. but here is another solution i used, you can try using `XLSX`:

```
  exportAsExcel() {
    const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.myData);
    const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'data');
    XLSX.writeFile(workBook, 'excel-export.xlsx');
  }
```

Comment: how about the API ? because i use API to export excel

Comment: i get my data via api in my service and call this function on a button. you can call you api at the beginning of this function or call in service